# How to pass selected struct to another view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm struggling to pass the right data to another View.
The idea is first to select the Task that has Status 0 and pass it to CardContentView to display under the Section of New tasks. If I print the values, its correct but it always displays the first data/array regardless of its Status. What could be done here?

```
struct Tasks: Identifiable {
            let id = UUID()
            let name: String
            let status: Int
            let image: String
        }
        extension Tasks {
        static var testData: [Tasks] {
            return [
                Tasks(name: "Inprogress", status: 1, image:"a1"),
                Tasks(name: "New", status: 0, image:"a2"),
            ]
        }
    }
```

ContentsView

```
struct ContentsView: View {
    @State var items: [Tasks]
    var size = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                let new = items.filter({$0.status == 0})
                let size = new.count
                if size > 0 {
                    Section(header:Text("\(size)" + " New")){
                        //let _ = print(new)
                        ForEach(new.indices, id: \.self) {itemIndex in
                            NavigationLink(destination: ChosenTask()) {
                                CardContentView(item: self.$items[itemIndex])

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("My tasks")
        }

    }
}
```

CardContentView

```
struct CardContentView: View {
    @Binding var item: Tasks

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 5) {
                Label("Name: " + (item.name), systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .labelStyle(.titleAndIcon)

            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            Image(item.image)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 60, height: 70)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you find yourself using indices in SwiftUI you are probably doing something wrong. Just use `ForEach(new) { item in ...}` and you need to pass `item` as a parameter to `ChosenTask` so that it has the right item to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already passing the item to another view when you call `CardContentView`. You just have to do the same thing and pass the item to `ChosenTask` in your `NavigationLink`. When the user taps the item, SwiftUI will take care of creating and displaying the `ChoseTask` view for you.

You should also avoid using indices. There is no need. Your struct conforms to `Identifiable` so you can use it directly

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                let new = items.filter({$0.status == 0})
                if !new.isEmpty {
                    Section(header:Text("\(size)" + " New")){
                        //let _ = print(new)
                        ForEach(new) {item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: ChosenTask(item: item)) {
                                CardContentView(item: item)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("My tasks")
        }

    }
```